# Can I set Drush to always use verbose?

Tags: drush

Its quite annoying to have to type -v.

Is there a way to change the drush settings so that it will always use verbose mode so I dont have to bother typing -v?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This works for me in Drush 5.

In a `drushrc.php` file (I tested with my `~/.drush/drushrc.php` you could do this per-project as well).

I simply added:

`$options['v'] = TRUE;` somewhere in the file. Then try issueing drush commands.

This works because of how [drush_parse_args](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/drush_parse_args/7) executes.

Comment: its easy when you know how :) works great, thanks a bunch!! I really dont know why this isnt standard behaviour

Comment: hehe ... in no linux program is `-v` "standard" behavior. It's only there if you need the crutch :)

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, if you're using bash or similar, just use the shell to add the argument:

```
alias drush='drush -v'
```

Put this in one of your `.bash_*` files. If you're already using an alias to invoke drush, you'll need to modify it.