# Why doesn't "drush --debug en color" show any output?

Tags: drush

Running `drush en color` from the /xampp/htdocs/drupal directory doesn't output anything. The same happens with `drush --debug en color`. Why?

Comment: try drush --debug en color and add the output to your question

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling drush? Did you get any errors while installing? Are you starting drush with the .bat file it has for windows?

Comment: Try the answer here:
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/60882/can-i-set-drush-to-always-use-verbose

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your drush installation is broken. So you have to reinstall it again.

The easiest way would be to install [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-windows) and follow the instructions from [drush-ops](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush#installupdate---a-global-drush-for-all-projects) (especially check [Windows](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush#installing-drush-on-windows) section). Then check [How to configure Drush on Windows 7?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/44686/how-to-configure-drush-on-windows-7)

If this is still happening, check your PATH environment variable if it contains the correct directories (maybe you have some non-drush binary within your system list of folders which could cause some conflict).